# how does convert_pytorch_model_to_tf() work?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, cleverhans

I'm playing with the [mnist_tutorial_pytorch.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/cleverhans/blob/master/cleverhans_tutorials/mnist_tutorial_pytorch.py), and I set the `eps = 0` in the `fgsm_params` dictionary.

Based on my understanding this means that `fgsm` attack should do nothing and the target model's accuracy will not decrease.

But I got a pytorch model which test accuracy is `99.05%` and the adv accuracy is `97.94%`. I noticed that this pytorch model is converted to a tensorflow model by the `convert_pytorch_model_to_tf()` function. 
So, is the decrease caused by the conversion or something else?

Parameters I have used for replication:

```
fgsm_params = {"eps": 0.3, "clip_min": 0.0, "clip_max": 1.0}  # I replaced 0.3 to 0.
```

Answer (score 0):

We now added support for PyTorch to CleverHans so you don't have to convert your model first. The FGSM attack can be found here: https://github.com/tensorflow/cleverhans/blob/master/cleverhans/future/torch/attacks/fast_gradient_method.py